# Use Bootstrap icons with NPM

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, icons

When I use any JS-module with NPM, I include it into my .js file with `require("")`. How can I do the same with [Bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/) and include them into .html?
Their official [docs](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage)  and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-icons) wasn't clear enough for me.

I don't use Bootstrap in my project, only few icons, is it enough to have only this package?

```
npm install bootstrap-icons
```

Are Bootstrap icons really free? Should you mention them in the project?

Answer (score 53):

Additional 28 June 2021

after import using NPM you can import CSS file to react with :

```
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
```

and use like this :

```
<i className="icon bi-envelope"></i>
```

if you only want to use the bootstrap-icons.svg from node_modules, you can copy it manually or with webpack. If you copy in root folder, you can use like this :

```
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
     <use xlink:href="bootstrap-icons.svg#bootstrap"/>
</svg>
```

If you copy in icons folder :

```
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
     <use xlink:href="icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#bootstrap"/>
</svg>
```

or copy the icons/*.svg for use only icon what you need, and you can use it like this :

```
<img src="bootstrap.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" title="Bootstrap">
```

> Are bootstrap icons really free?

yes, bootstrap icons is free https://github.com/twbs/icons/blob/main/LICENSE.md

> Should you mention them in the project?

you need to including copyright notice in your project. its enough, but if you want to mention it, create about page and included all software you use there that would be super nice.

note : Oct 2020

Comment: Was looking everywhere through their docs and online trying to figure out why the `<i class....></i>` wasn't working with my VueJS project. The `import` of the the `.css` was what was missing. Their doc doesn't cover that at all. Thanks.

Comment: Import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css". Not sure why this is missing in their docs, was looking for the file path to import and couldn't seem to find it mentioned anywhere. Thanks!!

Answer (score 27):

```
npm install bootstrap-icons
```

Then open your `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss`
and add the path to your `bootstrap-icons.css` file, usually, it should look like something like this

```
@import '~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
```

Comment: I imported to the main SCSS like this:

`@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons";`

Then use 

`<i class="bi bi-chevron-bar-right"></i>`

in HTML.
I see only white square.

Should i copy something else from the bootstrap-icons npm folder)?

Comment: This works for me only if I add explicitly add the .css extension in the include, otherwise it throws an error. So in your main scss file (that also holds the scss imports) do: `@import '~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';`

Comment: I was able to get this to work with a combination of the two comments above.  `@import '../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css`.  I tried importing with the tilde format, using the full relative path to the scss file, including the scss file.  But it only worked to use a relative path from the scss file to the css file in the bootstrap-icons project

Answer (score 0):

I installed the icons via npm

```
npm i bootstrap-icons
```

and added them to the style file

```
@import "~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons";
```

, but instead of the icons I have the same squares *(the same way I added Bootstrap styles from NPM and everything is fine with them)*. I tried all the add options from the documentation, nothing works (*except for a full-fledged SVG*).
[image: this is what the icons look like]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33380522)

Answer (score 0):

I installed the icons using yarn in my Next.js application

I followed the following steps

1. `yarn add bootstrap-icons`
2. Add `import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";` to the `index.tsx` file *(I'm using typescript)*
3. Test by adding an icon in the `index.tsx` like `<i className="bi bi-list"></i>`

It worked for me

Answer (score -3):

Add the following CDN to your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrapicons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31981648)

Answer (score -4):

`npm i bootstrap-icons`

Install this then import the below syntax.

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";

after that use this link in index.html

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">`
```

It's worked for me.

Comment: Loading from a CDN like this will completely negate installing via `npm i bootstrap-icons` - the accepted answer is correct